# Having a problem with npm global install on MacOS 11.6.1 with M1 chip

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to install npm in the terminal and I keep getting err messages.

The command is

```
`npm install -g ts-node`
```

and this is the err return

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin-script-deprecated.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/ts-script
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/ts- 
node/dist/bin-script-deprecated.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/ts-script'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/ts- 
node/dist/bin-script-deprecated.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/ts-script'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/ts-node/dist/bin-script-deprecated.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/ts-script'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aj/.npm/_logs/2021-11-10T21_41_24_060Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

npm has [an entire web page specifically on how to resolve the issue of `EACCES` errors when installing packages globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally). Find all the details there. They suggest many possible solutions. The one I would recommend, especially since you are presumably having this issue on a development machine, is to use a version manager like [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) instead of whatever package or whatever you used to install Node.js on your machine. But check the aforementioned web page for other options.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I'm headed there now. I just deleted all of my node files since i downloaded directly from the node.js site. currently installing with homebrew. will try to reinstall with nvm

Comment: Just went in and downloaded it. I dropped the -g and I had absolutely no problem. Any thoughts on why that may be?

Comment: @ajdaviscodes Yes, if you install without -g, then it will install as a dependency in your project `node_modules` rather than a global system directory. You are unikely to run into EACCES permission problems in that case.